# Use variable in single quotes

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a variable in my script.

This is the part that is burning my head:

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $Page -DefaultWebPartType People -WebPartProperties '{"title":"Primary Contact","persons":[{"id":"test@mail.de"}]}'
```

The test@mail needs to be replace with a variable. So the first attempt was:

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart -Page $Page -DefaultWebPartType People -WebPartProperties '{"title":"Primary Contact","persons":[{"id":"$varName"}]}'
```

This didn't worked. So I google and tried several options like $($varName), using ´´ and other..

Nothing of that worked. The variable is never really used, it uses the $varName as argument, what doesn't work obviously.

Comment: Replace `"` by `'` and vice versa. Then your variable will be evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double-quoted string literal and escape the double-quotes:

```
Add-PnPPageWebPart ... -WebPartProperties "{""title"":""Primary Contact"",""persons"":[{""id"":""$varName""}]}"
# or 
Add-PnPPageWebPart ... -WebPartProperties "{`"title`":`"Primary Contact`",`"persons`":[{`"id`":`"$varName`"}]}"
```